# Sorting a table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am rather new to VBA and I'm trying to learn through trial and error, recently I tried creating a table and then sorting that table based on a data set I have. When I try to sort this table that I have made it gives me the error "run-time error '1004' - Method  'Range' of object '_Global' failed" pointing towards the column of the table that I was trying to sort by.

The code I have is below:

```vb
Dim mainSheet As Worksheet

    Dim table As Range
    
    Set mainSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set table = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    
    mainSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, table, , xlYes).Name = "MainAccounts"
    
    Dim tableConverted As ListObject
    Dim propertyColumn As Range
    
    Set tableConverted = mainSheet.ListObjects("MainAccounts")
    Set propertyColumn = Range(tableConverted.Name & "[[#All],[property]]")
    
    With tableConverted.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=propertyColumn, SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending
        .Header = xlYes
        .Apply
    End With
```

I also tried instead of this type of range for the propertyColumn `Range("MainAccounts[Property]")` and this did not work either, It seems like its just not setting the propertyColumn variable to anything so I must not be point to something correctly somehow. If anyone could help that would be a lifesaver. Thank you!

Comment: The reason can be there is no `Property` named column. Check that no spaces leading or trailing and spelling is correct.

Comment: The column is named Property at the top,  however, im not sure how exactly the table is created within VBA, does it recognize the header names when creating?

Comment: Sure. The xlYes parameter is for that, means first row is header, as can be seen in the snapshot. For me both variations are work. The error is generated for me if either of the table's identifier is not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The same error may arise if there are no the Property column.

Though it may not be an ideal solution, you can also try the line of code below.

```
Set propertyColumn = tableConverted.ListColumns("property").DataBodyRange
```

Comment: Hi @Lutfor Rahman thank you for the reply, I tried this and it unfortunately had an error of `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range`, I feel as if the table isnt recognizing Property as a header for my table and Im not sure how to deal with this.

Comment: In your code, it seems there is nothing wrong. Please check if any white spaces exist in the cell at the beginning or end. If possible, you can share your dataset.

Comment: Hi Luftor Rahman It seems you were right, my property cell had a blank space at the end of it. Thank you so much haha!

Comment: You are most welcome! Zakmosbacher.

Answer (score 0):

- Please ensure to double-check that the creation of the ListObject has been successful.

[image]

```
    Set tableConverted = mainSheet.ListObjects("MainAccounts")
    ' Include the header row
    Set propertyColumnAll = tableConverted.ListColumns("property").Range
    ' Exclude the header row
    Set propertyColumnNoHeader1 = tableConverted.ListColumns("property").DataBodyRange

    ' OR
    ' Exclude the header row
    Set propertyColumnNoHeader2 = mainSheet.Range(tableConverted.Name & "[property]")
```

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [ListColumns object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listcolumns?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Hi @taller thank you for helping me out - when I try the first one you suggested using the ListColumns method it comes up with a `Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range` and the other method you showed comes with the same error as before. This is making me believe that I have created the table wrong somehow and the Property column is'nt showing? Please let me know your thoughts, Thank you!

Comment: Please check the table as I mentioned in reply. If it doesn't solve your issue, upload a screenshot which is simliar as mine.

Comment: Hi @taller here is what my table looks like after I run the macro and it catches an error at ` Set propertyColumn = Range(tableConverted.Name & "[[#All],[property]]")`

Comment: I added the image at the bottom of the main post.